# What are Application Pages, Site Pages and Content Pages?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

What are Application Pages, Site Pages and Content Pages

Comment: This question could be a great community wiki article, although I'm expecting to see an all-comprehensive answer within hours. It should be noted that there are already tens of existing questions about the matter, added by equally many blog posts of the topic. The mentioned are actually available to any by copy-pasting the title of the question to the nearest search engine.

Answer (score 0):

there are some differences between the application pages and site pages.
you can view this reference and also diagrammatic representation http://srisharepointdevelopment.blogspot.in/2011/07/app-page-vs-site-pages.html
 see the other reference also to get undestadning

http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2010/06/17/application-pages-vs-site-contnet-pages-vs-custom-aspx-pages/

Comment: Instead of providing links to external sources, you should edit the answer to provide content in such extent that it can on itself answer the original question. At the initial state, your question doesn't give any self-explanation or at least quoting which would answer the question.